# Dynamically create names inside a dictionary using multiple variables

Tags: python, dictionary, variables, dynamic

There have been similar questions but I've not quite been able to get it right - apologies for duplications. What I would like to do is create dataframe names inside a dictionary based on variables as I iterate.

```
d = {}
market = 'SPX'
datatype = 'prices'

for j in range(10):
    year = 2010+j
    start = str(year) + '-01-01'
    end = str(year+2) + '-01-01'
        
    d['{market}_{datatype}_from_{start}_to{end}'] = 'foo'
```

I would like for the elements of the dictionary to be called

```
spx_prices_from_2010-01-01_to_2012-01-01
spx_prices_from_2011-01-01_to_2013-01-01
...
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You have forgotten your string formatting. Change `d['{market}_{datatype}_from_{start}_to{end}']` to `d[f'{market}_{datatype}_from_{start}_to{end}']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Python 3, you can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
d = {}
market = 'SPX'
datatype = 'prices'

for j in range(10):
    year = 2010+j
    start = str(year) + '-01-01'
    end = str(year+2) + '-01-01'
        
    d[f"{market}_{datatype}_from_{start}_to_{end}"] = 'foo'
```

Alternatively, you can use `str`'s [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method.

Comment: Woha that was easy. Thank you so much!!

Comment: 1 more quick question if I haven't imposed too much already: is there an easy way of assigning the name of the dictionary itself - changing the name from d to "SPX_Prices" based on the variables?

Comment: I'd avoid that and just use a collection (e.g. d['SPX']['prices'] = ...).

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't do it... I think. I want to iterate through markets and datatypes - and for each create a dictionary of dataframes. So I want to name these dictionaries dynamically. Again, I'm super grateful

Comment: The dictionaries will just be embedded in an outer dictionary. You can write:
```
for market in markets:
    for datatype in datatypes:
        d["{}_{}".format(market, datatypes)] = ...
```
You can then access all the dictionaries with `d.values()`.

Comment: Thanks again - I'll try to figure that out. If you ever find yourself in Melbourne AU - I owe you a beer